# TypeError: can't convert type 'NoneType' to numerator/denominator

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here I try to calculate mean value based on the data in two list of `dict`s. Although I used same code before, I keep getting error. Is there any solution?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data3.csv',sep=';') # Reading data from csv
data = data.dropna(axis=0) # Drop rows with null values
data = data.T.to_dict().values() # Converting dataframe into list of dictionaries
newdata = pd.read_csv('newdata.csv',sep=';') # Reading data from csv
newdata = newdata.T.to_dict().values() # Converting dataframe into list of dictionaries

score = []
for item in newdata:
  score.append({item['Genre_Name']:item['Ranking']})


from statistics import mean
score={k:int(v) for i in score for k,v in i.items()}  

for item in data:
  y= mean(map(score.get,map(str.strip,item['Recommended_Genres'].split(','))))

print(y)
```

Too see csv files: https://repl.it/@rmakakgn/SVE2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get` method of `dict` return `None` if given key does not exist and `statistics.mean` fail due to that, consider that

```
import statistics
d = {"a":1,"c":3}
data = [d.get(x) for x in ("a","b","c")]
print(statistics.mean(data))
```

result in:

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'NoneType' to numerator/denominator
```

You need to remove `None`s before feeding into `statistics.mean`, which you can do using list comprehension:

```
import statistics
d = {"a":1,"c":3}
data = [d.get(x) for x in ("a","b","c")]
data = [i for i in data if i is not None]
print(statistics.mean(data))
```

or `filter`:

```
import statistics
d = {"a":1,"c":3}
data = [d.get(x) for x in ("a","b","c")]
data = filter(lambda x:x is not None,data)
print(statistics.mean(data))
```

(both snippets above code will print `2`)

In this particular case, you might get filter effect by replacing:

```
mean(map(score.get,map(str.strip,item['Recommended_Genres'].split(','))))
```

with:

```
mean([i for i in map(score.get,map(str.strip,item['Recommended_Genres'].split(','))) if i is not None])
```

though as with most python built-in and standard library functions accepting list as sole argument, you might decide to not build list but feed created generator directly i.e.

```
mean(i for i in map(score.get,map(str.strip,item['Recommended_Genres'].split(','))) if i is not None)
```

For further discussion see [PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) xor [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: Can you explain list comprehension based on my data? It is really complicated to me